# My Python script doesn't give me an error or shows any output

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, urllib2, simplejson

I'm creating a simple transit twitter-bot which posts a tweet to my API, then grabs the result to later on reply with an answer on travel times and such. All the magic is on the server-side , and this code should work just fine. Here's how:

A user composes like the tweet below:

```
@kollektiven Sundsvall Navet - Ljustadalen
```

My script removes the `@kollektiven` from the tweet, send the rest `Sundsvall Navet - Ljustadalen` to our API. Then a JSON should be given to the script. The script should later on  reply you with an answer like this:

```
@jackbillstrom Sundsvall busstation Navet (2014-01-08 20:45) till Ljustadalen centrum (Sundsvall kn) (2014-01-08 20:59)
```

But it doesn't. I'm using this code from github called [spritzbot](https://github.com/hiway/spritzbot). I edited the ***extensions/hello.py*** to look like the one below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json, urllib2, os

os.system("clear")

def process_mention(status, settings):
    print status.user.screen_name,':', status.text.encode('utf-8')
    urlencode = status.text.lower().replace(" ","%20") # URL-encoding
    tweet = urlencode.strip('@kollektiven ')
    try:
        call = "http://xn--datorkraftfrvrlden-xtb17a.se/kollektiven/proxy.php?input="+tweet # Endpoint
        endpoint = urllib2.urlopen(call) # GET-Request to API endpoint
        data = json.load(endpoint) # Load JSON
        answer = data['proxyOutput'] # The answer from the API
        return dict(response=str(answer)) # Posts answer tweet 

    except:
        return dict(response="Error, kontakta @jackbillstrom") # Error-meddelande
```

What is causing this problem? And why? I made some changes before I came to this revision, and it worked back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_mention(...)
    ...
```

Comment: It's a bit messy software, but the problem is inside my snippet. "extenstions/hello.py". To run the software, you run another file which proccesses the code inside my extension.
https://github.com/hiway/spritzbot/blob/master/spritzbot.py

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `process_mention` anywhere, just defining it.

Comment: Checkout the github repo, functions are mentioned there.

Comment: When you run the script, you run "spritzbot.py" which later on runs "extensions/hello.py"